# Supporting generic route for Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Web Api 2.2, and I am trying to achieve the following:
I have several controllers, and I want a global route that will look like
controller/{controller}/action/{action} - and I want the specific method to catch the call, whether it was in POST or GET (including its parameters).

For instance:

```
HTTP POST    /controller/users/action/getuser
{"user_id": 1234}
```

or

```
HTTP GET    /controller/users/action/getuser?user_id=1234
```

where the method is defined WITHOUT route:

```
public User getuser(int user_id)
{
...
}
```

I am unable to achieve that.
Assistance will be much appreciated.
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default route in your App_Start -> RouteConfig.cs

Under the method RegisterRoutes there should be a default route setter. 
You want to set something similar to :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "controller/{controller}/action/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Comment: Thinking about it, consider that there are some conventions: 
when you use a "getuser" as a method name under a User controller he will parse it as a get method applied to the controller.

Probably the easiest way to do it is to use a route prefix attribute on the controller and a a route attribute on each method.

Otherwise you have to modify the routing behaviour of all the webapi, modifying the controller selector.